# Ignorar valores observable hasta que haya pasado un periodo de tiempo

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Tengo un observable que emite valores en ráfagas. Quiero de cada ráfaga tomar el primer valor e ignorar el resto. Intento explicarlo mejor, emite:

```
--A-B-C-D--------E-F-G------H
```

Yo quiero capturar A pero hasta que no haya pasado un segundo, por ejemplo, ignorar el resto de valores, pero cuando haya pasado el tiempo no quiero que me devuelva el último valor quiero que no devuelva nada hasta que vuelva a emitir un valor.

En este caso quiero que la salida sea:

```
--A-------------E-----------H---
```

He probado con todos los operadores de tiempo que hay y no lo consigo.

Comment: Sin código que examinar no hay respuesta que dar.

Comment: ¿No te vale [debounceTime](https://rxmarbles.com/#debounceTime)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador que buscas es el [throttle](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle), este operador ignora los parámetros que le entran durante un tiempo indicado.

En el ejemplo utilizo el [throttleTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime) que te permite pasarle directamente el tiempo en milisegundos

he construido un ejemplo para que veas como funciona [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-e4utfh):

```
const test = new Subject<string>();

test.pipe(throttleTime(1000)).subscribe(res => {
  console.log("res");
  console.log(res);
});

test.next("A");
test.next("B");
test.next("C");
test.next("D");


setTimeout(() => {
  test.next("E");
  test.next("F");
  test.next("G");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  test.next("H");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Bien visto, estaba mirando este operador para poner una respuesat pero no me estaba quedando claro el uso de la configuración (las opciones leading y trailing)

Comment: Hola Pablo, la verdad que estos dos parametros de configuración no me quedan muy claro, pero creo que puedes llegar a controlar el primero y el ultimo item del bloque. es decir podrías llegar hacer que te llege el A y el D, la E y la G, y la H. o solo que te llege la 'D', la 'G' y la 'H'. es un poco raro.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente era ese el que buscaba, lo había probado, pero no me estaba funcionando por otro fallo y es que tenía que ignorar el primer valor que venía vacío ya que tomaba este valor y con el throttleTime se saltaba el segundo.